# iOS: CAShapeLayer, CALayer mask, hitTest:WithEvents, hitTest:

Tags: ios, calayer, hittest, cashapelayer

Thanks in advance: I have a view hierarchy like this:

A `UIView` 
within this I set: `CALayer * layer = (CALayer*) self.layer`

And within this class I have a `CAShapeLayer`, which is set as the mask of the `CALayer`.

It animates fine, no problem.

I have a `UIViewController` that init the above `UIView` by:

`myView = [myAnimationView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0, 0}, 320, 450}];
[self.view addSubview myView];`

So what I have is: a `UIView` class and the above `UIViewController` class. Nothing else.

As the `CAShapeLayer` animates (it is only a basic ca animation, scaling from a small circle to a larger one), I hope to be able to get the touch point within `UIViewController` that inits this `UIView`

Should I use hitTest:WithEvents: here? I have tried it, but it get called three times. The returned points are correct, but I was hoping to find a way to know whether or not an animated view is being touched from the container view. Other words, I would like to know if  the subView /subLayer is being touched.

In summary, here is my view hierarchy:

`UIViewController` initializes the `UIView` class and adds it as subView.
Within this `UIView` class its layer is set to be `CALayer` by `CALayer * layer = (CALayer *) self.layer` and the `CAShapeLayer` is set to be the mask of the `CALayer` and animation is set on the shape layer's path.

And I would like to to able to get the layer touched within `UIViewController`

Is it possible to get the touch point from a layer that is being animated by CAShapeLayer within a view whose layer is set to be `CALayer` from a `UIViewController` that adds it as its subview? Please cite with examples.

Thanks very much in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think `CALayer` isn't designed to receive/handle touch events (which is one big difference to `UIView`).
I tested for a (long press) touch within a `CAShapeLayer.path` from the ViewController with something like

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint currentPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.overlayView];
    bool didSelect = [self selectPathContainingPoint:currentPoint];
    if (didSelect) {
        [self updateViews];
    }
}

- (BOOL)selectPathContainingPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CALayer * layer = (CALayer *) self.layer;
    CAShapeLayer *mask = (CAShapeLayer *)layer.mask;
    return CGPathContainsPoint(mask.path, nil, point);
}
```

There's one caveat however: my path isn't animated. In the docs for CAShapeLayer it also doesn't say anything if the `CAShapeLayer.path` property updates during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)setup
{
    _maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    _maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    _maskLayer.path = somePath;

    _theLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    // Apply a mask
    _maskLayer.frame = _theLayer.frame;
    _theLayer.mask = _maskLayer;
}

- (IBAction)tapOnView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:theView];
    CALayer *subLayer = [_theLayer.presentationLayer hitTest:point].modelLayer;

    if (subLayer != _theLayer && subLayer != nil) {
        // Do something with the sublayer which the user touched
    }
}
```

You will have to setup your TapGestureRecognizer, I did this using Interface Builder but you can do it in code if you want. Be sure that your layers have proper bounds setup, and you also need to set the bounds on your mask.

Notice that I am getting the presentationLayer and the converting it back to the real layer. This will cause it to work with animations.

I hope this works for you.